# Windows 10 taskbar right click doesn't work properly

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, right-click

[image]

So I've had this problem for quite some time, I can't really explain it in the title.

I'm running Windows 10 and when I right-click on the icon of a running program on the taskbar the only option I get is close window. This makes pinning/ unpinning programs impossible, as well as using other options that normally should appear. If I press the "close window" button, nothing happens.

I get the same thing even for windows processes (windows explorer / windows media player).

On icons of programs that aren't running, I get "unpin from taskbar" as an only option when right-clicking on the icon, which doesn't work as well.

Using the Windows Start menu, search bar and right-clicking on the taskbar works fine, I can open the Task Manager etc. The only problem is with program icons.

Comment: Seems to be the same issue as these posts: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-explorer-will-not-pin-to-the-taskbar/4016d318-32cf-4893-83e7-c8a15b566341 There are a lot of options you can try in this and linked threads.

Comment: I did not get the question

Comment: this absolutely is the issue i had these days, have you found the solution?

Comment: Rather than re-posting a new answer here, I'll just link an answer I made elsewhere after fixing my own issue like this one:  https://superuser.com/a/1663490/154827

Answer (score 0):

I've been googling and testing myself for more than an hour now but I can't seem to find a direct fix to your problem. However I think that there is one thing that might work.

Settings >> Personalization >> Start.
[image: Personalization]

There's a On/Off button called "Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the taskbar." if you try turning it Off and then rebooting and turning it back On your Jump Lists might work again. If it doesn't work, I suggest that you check if there is any updates available.

Further reading on a Microsoft forum addressing the same issue:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/jump-lists-not-working-in-windows-10/f03cd014-6784-4d81-8735-3beb9877db5a

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the jump lists. Even with the jump lists disabled the context menu should show at least three entries, Close Window, Pin/unpin and the program itself.

Comment: Well it is called a jump list, have you tried rebooting?

Comment: @Bungicasse 
I tried turning on/off the option in Personalisation and restarting but it didnt help.

Im gonna run a system file check in case some windows file is corrupt, if it doesnt find anything I'll try what the guys from the Microsoft forum suggested (thanks for the link).

If something changes I'll post more.

Answer (score -1):

*Ctrl+Alt+Del*(**Task Manager**), find **Windows Explorer**, *right click*, **Restart**, it takes 10 secs. or less the whole process

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't change anything. The taskbar is like that from the very moment the OS boots. 

I feel like some corrupted file is causing the error, I'll be reinstalling Windows soon anyways so it will be fixed.

Comment: That is not a solution. It is a workaround. And, it is not even permanent.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+Del opens the special screen, not task manager. The shortcut for opening task manager is Ctrl+Shift+Esc